# Adding javascript code to URL

Tags: javascript, url

I' ve written some line of js code to sum some values in a specific page. To use my function, i usually open the target page with Chrome, i open the console,i paste my code and call the function. Is there a way to load page and inject code automatically in the URL or somewhere else?

Comment: you need to do it either with a custom browser extension, or automate the browser window via another script and inject the code programatically

Answer (score 0):

Just include it in between `<script>` tags on that page:

```
<script>
// Your code
</script>
```

You can place them just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: the page isn' t mine of course. it's an external URL on a private server

Comment: It is not possible to inject scripts to the pages you don't own. EDIT: You might try to use Bookmarklets - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet - but they can only operate on functions available on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 <div>some HTML</div>

<!--add the script to your html file-->
<script src="script/url.js"></script>

<script>
    myFunction(); //function call
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can add a bookmark with this code at the place of the URL:

  javascript:(function(){
    alert('ok');//place here you're personal script
  })();
- You can use a userscript:

  - [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) for Chrome
  - [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox
- You can use a browser extension:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions